# Raphael animation callback function not working?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I am most likely misusing this call back feature but in the following code, the "testCircle" performs no animation before disappearing.

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 1280,600);


    var testCircle = paper.circle(300, 300, 50);

    testCircle.animate({
        cx: 700
    }, 1000, testCircle.remove())
```

I want the animation to actually finish before the circle is removed. Am I misusing this function?

Comment: Just to extend Brians answer, you are immediately calling your remove function, rather than include a function (that isn't executed immediately). So you could just change testCircle.remove() to testCircle.remove

Comment: You should probably accept the answers to your questions. People will stop answering you if you ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DktHL/453/)**

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 1280,600);
var testCircle = paper.circle(300, 300, 50).attr('fill','red');

testCircle.animate({cx: 700}, 1000, hideCircle);

function hideCircle()
{
    testCircle.remove();
}
```